# Short story about a survivor in a very hot climate future NY

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

Interview magazine ran a short story about a person who went searching for cans of food on a ship mired in dried up New York's harbor, walking in the hot sun to the ship looking for a container of food. The story had to be late 70's, early 80's and has been in my thoughts during these days of climate change. The narrator had to walk in the early morning and evening, the sun too hot to even go out during the day, water gone everywhere.

Comment: I thought the sea levels were supposed to *rise*?

Comment: @user14111 - All the water has evaporated.